# create a random for strings

Tags: java, string, random

I recently started java programming and I was wondering I wrote some string and initialized their variables but how can I now randomize those variables so that one is chosen randomly everytime. I'm sorry if this is vague and please be expalantory I'm only a beginner

Regards

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to generate a random String?

Comment: Why not include what you've done so far? Don't be shy...

Comment: Don't apologize for being "vague", take the effort to not be vague. If you want explicit answers you need to ask an explicit question. Bathsheba is correct in suggesting that you show us what you have tried. This will help us to understand what you are attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
String str= "your string";
int n = str.length();
Random random= new Random();
String randomString= "";
for (int i = 0; i <length you want; i++) 
    randomString+= new String(str.charAt(random.nextInt(n)));
```

Comment: Can you stop changing it every 2 seconds, or use proper Java standards right away? Thanks!

Comment: @Dropout sorry  i have small mistake.So i did like that

Comment: No problem, I was just making the same few edits all over again.. :D

Comment: is alphabet supposed to be str? Also, (in my version of Java at least) string will not accept a char as a initialisation parameter. It will however accept it after string+=

Comment: @PSR does `new String(str.charAt(random.nextInt(n)));` work in your version of java? If so thats very interesting? Plus just my opinion but isnt the multiline-braceless-if (http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful) and by extention the multiline-braceless-for considered bad practice? I know it caused me to introduce a bug when I was trying to run your code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to choose one object at random from a number of choices, put them in an array, and then pick a random index.

```
Object[] choices = new Object[] { a, b, c};
int randomIndex = Math.random() * choices.length;
Object picked = choices[randomIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the  RandomStringUtil class of apache [commons.lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)